# Htaccess redirect without define hardcoded domainname

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I find a lot lot lot questions about redirection with htaccess.
However it seems no one has the same "problem" as me.

What I want is redirect if a directory is accessed, it should redirect to the subdomain. So far its good and working. However, I dont want to change my htaccess all the time when a domainname is changed.

So I have:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subdir/(.*)$ http://subdir.example.com/$1
```

But in my case I put my application on the domain example2.com, I have to change the name.
Is it possible to have something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^**(capture_hostname)**/subdir/(.*)$ http://subdir.**(put_hostname_here)**/$1
```

All "solutions" seems to work with defining the domainname in htaccess.
I work not enough with htaccess to solve this issue. Therefore we are together :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `mod_rewrite` rules and capture hostname from a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(subdir)(/.*)?$ http://$1.%1$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

`%1` is the value being captured from `RewriteCond` directive, `$1` is `subdir` and `$2` is part after `subdir/`

Comment: That is because you had trailing slash missing after `subdir`. See my updated answer, it will work with `https://localhost/subdir` as well.

Comment: Thats correct, it working nice now :)
Testing can be easy with: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/